# A list question is opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, vote-to-close

[How could a hypothetical corrupt basketball federation change game / tournament formats to favour a team?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/28689/how-could-a-hypothetical-corrupt-basketball-federation-change-game-tournament)

It's a list question like

Besides iCarly, has there ever been an (official) adult sequel to a kids' series?

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/117455/besides-icarly-has-there-ever-been-an-official-adult-sequel-to-a-kids-series

Comment: List of *what*, though? The title is certainly opinion-based, as it refers to a hypothetical scenario, and while the body says "Any others?", it's not clear what you mean by that. Any other *what?*

Comment: I don't see any relevance in a question from an entirely different site to attempt defending just one of the problematic aspects of a question on this site.

Answer (score 4):

List questions aren't really good fits for Stack Exchange as a general rule, though there are exceptions to be made in some communities - such as this one.  But they're *specific* exceptions, not *general* ones.  Stack Exchange sites really are built for the one question, one answer format - where each answer attempts to be *the* answer for the question.

In our case, we allow list questions when it's lists of sports accomplishments or statistics, basically - "who has scored more than 100 goals in the history of International Soccer/Football", that sort of thing.

Your question combines several issues: it starts from a somewhat biased viewpoint (which isn't "opinion based" per se, but it's definitely inserting opinion into the question) and it doesn't have a specific answer - it's just asking for ideas, more of a forum post.  This is a good fit for reddit, perhaps, but not here.